# How does thread.join() work conceptually?

Tags: java, multithreading

From the docs:

> The join method allows one thread to wait for the completion of
>   another. If t is a Thread object whose thread is currently executing,
>
> `t.join();`
>
> causes the current thread to pause execution until t's thread
>   terminates

What I can't get my head around is that this is a method on a thread that's different to one it's being called from. So if a thread `t1` calls another thread's `t2.join()`, `t2` knows nothing about `t1`. So what's actually happening under the hood to make `t1` wait for `t2` for finish?

Comment: It's almost certainly modeled after (and implemented with) [`pthread_join(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html); and in Java (like with `this`) a thread can get its context with [`Thread.currentThread()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread--)

Comment: t1 tells the operating system "hey, please wake me up when t2 finishes".

When t2 finishes, the operating system checks if any other threads are waiting for t1 to finish and wakes them up.

(I didn't think this was enough detail to be an actual answer)

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the Java source code:

calling t2.join() from t1 will make t1 wait on t2 object (t2 is a `Thread`, which is a subclass of `Object`). The wait will be forever as long as t1 is alive. When t2 thread finishes its work, it will call `Object.notifyAll()` so t1 awakens.

Comment: Per documentation this.notifyAll() will be called

Comment: `notifyAll`. If it was `notify` then only one `join` would wake up (other than for spurious wakeups).

Answer (score 0):

The classic implementation of `Thread.join` (other implementations are possible, is to lock the `Thread` object, test to see if is alive and if not `wait` on the `Thread` object. As a thread exits, it locks its instance and calls `notifyAll`.

The choice of a public object as the lock is unfortunate.